# System.unexpected exception when I run Reports.ReportManager.runReport(Id,true) within for loop

Tags: apex, exception, reports-api

I am facing System.unexpected exception when I excecute below code.

```
List<Report> repList=[SELECT Id, name,DeveloperName, Format 
                      FROM Report 
                      WHERE Format='Tabular' 
                      LIMIT 10];
for(Integer i=0; i<repList.size(); i++){
  Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(repList[i],true);     
}
```

I have tried by keeping list of reports in Map then get the id and passes to runReport(). Even though I am getting this error. I also tried to runReport asynchronously but same issue.
Please can You asssist anybody ASAP. Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Report ID in the runReport method.

```
Reports.ReportManager.runReport(repList[i].id,true);
```